# Unidentified R.java after blue screen of death

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My computer crashed (Got the blue screen of death).
After that I was unable to open my project again, however, it's files were still present.
So I opened a new project and created all the files again and then copied the content inside.

Everything went well except for errors in all of my java files: "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

Additional info:

> 1. My Android SDK Build-tools are installed
> 2. The new project I created has the same name exactly,  except for an aditional char "3" at the end of it [example: test3 instead of test],
>      and I editted the menifest file properly and also every java file to
>      contain the propper package name.
> 3. My R.java file is present [I'm using Eclipse, Windows7]

Would very appreciate help in solving this.

Comment: What happens if you to a Project/Clean? does R.java reappear in you gen folder?

Comment: Check your res folder files.

Comment: @Klaus66:
Yes: it reappears immediately when i delete it (even before I have the chance to clean)
And when I clean it remains as it is

Comment: @Vipul:
I checked each of them

Comment: So, it's OK - you don't have to touch that file. If it **missing**, then there's something wrong with one or more of your xml files. R.java contains all the references to your UI elements - don't delete it!

Comment: @Klauss66:
Thanks,but I know that. and as i wrote- when its being deleted it reappears!  (and I did that to check if clean will work afterwards)

Comment: If you're using Eclipse: 1) Turn auto build off and do a manual build; 2) Or, close Eclipse, delete the `.lock` file found under `\workspaces\.metadata\` directory, then do a manual build. Sometimes this lock file prevents you from creating a new **R.java**. Also, if you set your project to auto build, the **R.java** will be created automatically by your IDE as soon as you deleted it.

Comment: Thank you Chuong
Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a quite common issue when using Eclipse for Android development but for some reasons, Eclipse isn't exit properly; re-opening the project will see the error logs of `R.java ...`.

I suggest to remove the project from workspace (don't delete local files), copy your project source code to another directory. From Eclipse, `File -> Open Existing Android Project`, find the project source directory to re-add into workspace. Update the SDK version and dependencies. Usually, it should be fine at this step.

For experienced developers, I guess you know how to check file lock (@ChuongPham mentioned in comment above) and check for wrong resources references in projects manually...

Comment: I went over each of the files i'v created in my project (for about an hour and a half!) and found no problem with the refrences.
about files being created automathicaly I don't know (except for R.java which seems fine).

I did what you said and the same problem remains

Comment: Hello friends, 
After investigating I found that the problem was the menifest file.
Aparently its forbidden to change the package name and it caused the error, I just didn't know it at that time.

Thanks for you who tried to help and I hope that it will at least help someone who has the same error.

Comment: @user3134572: it's good if you can post the error show in the log.

Comment: Sure, as i wrote:
"R cannot be resolved to a variable" and that was the only error and that is why it was hard to find.

it's not trivial and i invested a lot of time and effort to investigate the process on its many aspects and its discouraging for me to see that -1